# ¿Como imprimir reportes en FPDF filtrado por fechas?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, fpdf

Alguien ha realizado algún formulario que les permita generar reportes filtrados por fecha. Tengo un crud que me permite imprimir cada reporte por fila, Lo que quiero es generar un solo PDF, pero que estén los datos en diferentes hojas. No se me entiendan

[image: Formato PDF]

Lo que quiero es mostrar este mismo formato, en un Solo PDF, por ejemplo si en la fecha de hoy hubo 3 registros, me muestre 3 hojas con el mismo formato en un solo PDF

Tengo este Crud que al presionar el botón de impresora me muestra el reporte que muestro de ejemplo, Me muestra los datos por fila.

[image: crud]

Lo que requiero que generar Estos mismos reportes, filtrador por fecha y no presionando uno por uno el botón de print, les dejo mi código del reporte.

```js
<?php

use JetBrains\PhpStorm\ArrayShape;

include('PDF_MC_Table.php');
require_once '../controlador/conexion.php';
$objeto = new Conexion();
$conexion = $objeto->Conectar();

$id_row = $_GET['id'];

$pdf = new FPDF($orientation = 'P', $unit = 'mm');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 20);
$textypos = 5;
$pdf->setY(12);
$pdf->setX(10);

//Consulta a la base de datos
$resultado = $conexion->query("SELECT *, CASE 
WHEN cuadrilla =1 THEN 'Cuadrilla de Operación Ciudad'
WHEN cuadrilla =2 THEN 'Cuadrilla de Operación Mega sistema'
WHEN cuadrilla =3 THEN 'Cuadrilla de Drenajes'
WHEN cuadrilla =4 THEN 'Cuadrilla de Tomas tapadas'
WHEN cuadrilla =5 THEN 'Cuadrilla de Cloración'
WHEN cuadrilla =6 THEN 'Cuadrilla de Bacheo'
WHEN cuadrilla =7 THEN 'Cuadrilla de Contratos'
WHEN cuadrilla =8 THEN 'otros'
ELSE 'Cuadrilla desconocida'
END cuadrillas FROM sanandre_cmaps.reportes WHERE id=$id_row");
//$resultado = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM reportes WHERE id=$id_row");
$data = $resultado->fetchAll();

// Agregamos los datos de la empresa
//$pdf->Cell(5, $textypos, "ORDEN DE TRABAJO CMAPS");
$pdf->Image('logo.jpg', 35, 10, 133);
$pdf->setY(30);
$pdf->setX(10);
$pdf->Cell(185, 20, utf8_decode('ORDEN DE TRABAJO CMAPS'), 0, 0, 'C');
date_default_timezone_set('America/mexico_city');

// Agregamos los datos de la orden
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
$pdf->setY(30);
$pdf->setX(135);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 8);
$pdf->setY(35);
$pdf->setX(135);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 8);
$pdf->Cell(54, 45, "Hora: " . date('H:i:s'), 0, 1, 'R');
$pdf->setY(40);
$pdf->setX(135);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 8);
$pdf->Cell(55, 45, "Fecha: " . date("d/m/y"), 0, 1, "R");
$pdf->setY(75);
$pdf->setX(80);
$pdf->Cell(5, $textypos, "DATOS DE LA PERSONA QUE REPORTA");
$pdf->setY(120);
$pdf->setX(80);
$pdf->Cell(5, $textypos, "CUADRILLA RESPONSABLE");
$pdf->setY(160);
$pdf->setX(80);
$pdf->Cell(5, $textypos, utf8_decode("FINALIZACIÓN DEL TRABAJO"));

//Mueve la posición del Array Folio
$pdf->setY(55);
$pdf->setX(10);
//// Array de Cabecera Folio
$header = array (utf8_decode("N.DE ORDEN:"));

// Column widths
$w = array(20);
// Header
for ($i = 0; $i < count($header); $i++)
    $pdf->Cell($w[$i], 7, $header[$i], 2, 0,);
$pdf->Ln();
// Data
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $pdf->SetXY(30, 55);
    $pdf->Cell($w[0], 7, utf8_decode($row['folio']), 0,);
    $pdf->Ln();
}
$pdf->setY(153);
$pdf->setX(138);
//// Array de Cabecera Fecha y hora Finalizado
$header = array (utf8_decode("FECHA Y HORA DE FINALIZACIÓN"));

// Column widths
$w = array(64);
// Header
for ($i = 0; $i < count($header); $i++)
    $pdf->Cell($w[$i], 7, $header[$i], 1, 0,'C');
$pdf->Ln();
// Data
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $pdf->SetXY(138, 160);
    $pdf->Cell($w[0], 7, utf8_decode($row['otros']), 1,);
    $pdf->Ln();
}

/// Apartir de aqui empezamos con la tabla de Orden
$pdf->setY(80);
$pdf->setX(135);
$pdf->Ln();

//// Array de Cabecera
$header = array("NOMBRE(S)", "APELLIDOS", utf8_decode("DIRECCIÓN"), utf8_decode("TELÉFONO"), "CONTRATO");

// Column widths
$w = array(30, 40, 80, 20, 22,);
// Header
for ($i = 0; $i < count($header); $i++)
    $pdf->Cell($w[$i], 5, $header[$i], 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Ln();
// Data
$total = 0;
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $pdf->Cell($w[0], 12, utf8_decode($row["nombre"]), 1);
    $pdf->Cell($w[1], 12, utf8_decode($row["apellido"]), 1);
    $pdf->MultiCell($w[2], 5, utf8_decode($row["direccion"]), 1);
    //cambia la posicion de los cuadros telefono y medidor
    $pdf->SetXY(160, 92);
    $pdf->Cell($w[3], 12, utf8_decode($row["telefono"]), 1);
    $pdf->Cell($w[4], 12, utf8_decode($row["num_contrato"]), 1);
    $pdf->Ln();
}

// Apartir de aqui empezamos con la tabla de Cuadrilla
$pdf->setY(115);
$pdf->setX(135);
$pdf->Ln();

//// Array de Cabecera
$header = array("TURNADO A", utf8_decode("SUBDIRECCIÓN"), "RESPONSABLE", "NOMBRE(S)", "FECHA");

// Column widths
$w = array(45, 40, 40, 40, 27);
// Header
for ($i = 0; $i < count($header); $i++)
    $pdf->Cell($w[$i], 5, $header[$i], 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Ln();
// Data
foreach ($data as $row) {
    //$pdf->Cell($w[0], 6, $row[utf8_decode('cuadrillas')], 1);
    $pdf->Cell($w[0], 12, utf8_decode($row["cuadrillas"]), 1);
    $pdf->Cell($w[1], 12, utf8_decode($row["otros"]), 1);
    $pdf->Cell($w[2], 12, utf8_decode($row["otros"]), 1);
    $pdf->Cell($w[3], 12, utf8_decode($row["otros"]), 1);
    $pdf->Cell($w[4], 12, utf8_decode($row["otros"]), 1);
    $pdf->Ln();
}

// Apartir de aqui empezamos con la tabla de tipo de orden
$pdf->setY(155);
$pdf->setX(135);
$pdf->Ln();

//// Array de Cabecera
$header = array("PROBLEMA REPORTADO", utf8_decode("OBSERVACIÓN"), utf8_decode("CENTRO DE ATENCIÓN USUARIOS"));

// Column widths
$w = array(64, 64, 64);
// Header
for ($i = 0; $i < count($header); $i++)
    $pdf->Cell($w[$i], 7, $header[$i], 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Ln();
// Data
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $pdf->MultiCell($w[0], 5, utf8_decode($row["observaciones"]), 1);
    $pdf->SetXY(74, 174);
    $pdf->Cell($w[1], 20, utf8_decode($row['otra_descripcion']), 1);
    $pdf->Cell($w[2], 20, utf8_decode($row['otros']), 1);
    $pdf->Ln();
}


// Apartir de aqui empezamos con la tabla de Martial y Herramientas
$pdf->setY(190);
$pdf->setX(195);
$pdf->Ln();
/////////////////////////////
//// Array de Cabecera
$header = array("MATERIAL Y HERRAMIENTAS UTILIZADAS");
//// Arrar de Productos
$products = array(
    array(""),
);
// Column widths
$w = array(193);
// Header
for ($i = 0; $i < count($header); $i++)
    $pdf->Cell($w[$i], 7, $header[$i], 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Ln();
// Data
$total = 0;
foreach ($products as $row) {
    $pdf->Cell($w[0], 35, $row[0], 1);
    $pdf->Ln();
}

//Firma del uuario.
$pdf->setY(253);
$pdf->setX(10);
$pdf->Cell(120, 20, utf8_decode('____________________________'), 0, 0, 'C');
$pdf->setY(256);
$pdf->setX(10);
$pdf->Cell(120, 20, utf8_decode('FIMA DEL USUARIO'), 0, 0, 'C');

//Firma del Reponsable
$pdf->setY(253);
$pdf->setX(20);
$pdf->Cell(230, 20, utf8_decode('____________________________'), 0, 0, 'C');
$pdf->setY(256);
$pdf->setX(20);
$pdf->Cell(230, 20, utf8_decode('CUADRILLA'), 0, 0, 'C');

$pdf->output();
```

Comment: Veo que etiquetas la pregunta con **fpdf** y **php**, entre otras. Pues lo que quieres hacer, entiendo que es un bucle de registros, y para cada registro haces una llamada al método `$pdf->addPage();`, ¿no? (Entendiendo que el objeto lo declaras en `$pdf`) Yo personalmente suelo utilizar otras utilidades (como FPDFI), pero para lo que planteas fpdf te sobrará

Comment: ¿Tienes algún ejemplo? Puedo subir el código de mi PDF, para que me puedas orientar. @VFG

Comment: [@andrés-de-jesús](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/132917/andr%c3%a9s-de-jes%c3%bas), lo normal es que subas tu código sin temas privados o intrascendentes para la resolución con el intento que has hecho hasta ahora, que digas qué es lo que funciona mal y nosotros ayudemos **corrigiéndolo** (no haciéndolo, porque sería hacer el trabajo o la tarea).

Comment: Excelente, enseguida lo agrego.

Comment: @VFG ya lo subí, espero me puedas ayudar

Comment: Hay un problema de partida, y es que almacenas todos tus registros (aunque con el filtrado de `$id_row` deberías tener sólo uno) en `$data` y después utilizas no sé cuántas veces el `foreach ($data as $row) {`. En realidad deberías hacer el `foreach` justo después del `fetchAll` y meter todo ahí: generar una página para cada `$row` y después todo lo demás. Porque quieres hacer lo mismo para cada fila. Además se simplifica todo mucho y se hace más legible. Y para filtrar por fecha en lugar de `$id_row` será `[...] FROM sanandre_cmaps.reportes WHERE [[[campofecha]]]='$filtrofecha'`

Comment: De acuerdo, Lo intentaré, :) ya me diste una idea. ¿Si tengo dudas puedo consultarte nuevamente?

Comment: @VFG NO TUVE EXITO